# Get filenames from a directory in Android

Tags: android, list, filenames

I want to populate a spinner with the filenames of files found on the SD card with specific extensions. I can get it thus far to populate the spinner with the correct files, but the path is shown as well.

Can anyone tell me how to only get the filename of a specific file in a directory on the SD card?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "path");
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        String name = f.getName();
        // Do your stuff
}
```

Have a look at **[Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)** page for more info.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in JNI?

Comment: this code is giving NPE. Check my answer below. That worked for me. BTW plus 1 for nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard, "yourpath");
for (File f : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile())
        String name = f.getName();
        // do whatever you want with filename
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File filePath= new File(File Address);
File[] fileList = filePath.listFiles();
String name = fileList [0].getName().toString();
```

Comment: not very useful without explanation & doesn't address the specific question (filter by name/extension)

Answer (score 0):

could you process the string in reverse order(right to left), finding the first slash, then cutting the string at that point and taking the rightmost part of the string as the filename ?

Answer (score 0):

use method getName() of file object:

```
file.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are giving null pointer exception in my case. Following code worked for me:

```
File yourDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/WhatsApp/Databases");
    for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile())
            name = f.getName();
        // Do your stuff
}
```